# Converting a string to opencv Point

Tags: c++, string, opencv

I have a file which contains the coordinate values of a point in each frame of my video file... I am reading this text file and trying to get this coordinate values. I read these values as string. For example `[631,332]`. I need to convert this string to a `cv::Point` value. I am using C++. Do I have to split it and get the integer values and convert it to Point??? Or is there any other method?

Comment: @Amit Now iam splitting the string and converting string to integer values and then using these values for creating Point

Comment: @Neeraj sounds good, so whats the problem? You should add your attempted solution. No better way to do it that I know of.

Comment: @Amith Thats pretty straight forward... removed first and last [] then splitted with , then converted it to int... then again using this integer values created Point...

Comment: Does that work? Are you happy with that code?

Comment: @Amit Yes Of course... But it is not so beautiful from a programmer's perspective.. :D

Comment: Not sure that it will perform better but you could take a look at `sscanf` - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/ - perhaps like `sscanf(line, "[%d,%d]", &x, &y)`

Comment: So you have perfectly working, simple to understand, short, portable code. Please delete this question.

Comment: @StillLearning Yeah its works ... Converted string to char* then it works.. Great.. Even the logic is same.. it reduced to 2 line.. Thanks..

Comment: Yes, if `line` is a `std::string` you'll need `line.c_str()` to convert it to `char*` BTW: The number of code lines should not be your prime goal - look at performance instead. In most cases you will however get best performance and best maintainable code by using library functions.... Remember to check the return value of `sscanf` to ensure correct operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++ input from txt (Formatted input) is the job of `>>`. Define your own [`operator >>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2). Something like:

```
istream& operator >> (istream &fi, cv::Point &p)
{
   char char1, char2, char3;
   fi >> char1 >> p.x >>char2 >> p.y >> char3;
   if (!fi) return bad_istream; 
   if (char1=='[' &&  char2==',' && char3==']')
      return fi;
   else
      throw bad_input_Point_format;
}
```

And simple use the `>>` to input yours `Point`s

(eventually `bad_input_Point_format` could be an exception class derived from `bad_istream`)
Alternatively, if you don't want to throw you could experiment with [setstate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) to set an error flag in fi and return that.

Bjarne Stroustrup:

> Look up gets() and scanf() in your documentation and avoid them like the plague. By “dangerous,”
>   we mean that such buffer overflows are a staple of “cracking” — that is, break-ins — on computers.
>   Many implementations now warn against gets() and its cousins for exactly this reason.